# Take multiple values of the array by indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D array A: nxn with values of a function, and I want to take the values in different arrays for the black values, white values and gray values.

[image: Matrix]

For example for the black and white values I wrote:

```
black_values = A[::2,::2]
white_values = A[1::2,1::2]
```

How to get the gray values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` is a 2D numpy array then:

```
A[::2,::2]
```

should get what you want.

Comment: This fetches the black values and already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the number of gray values are twice that of either black or white values. So you might use two arrays to store gray values.

```py
g1 = A[::2, 1::2]
g2 = A[1::2, ::2]
```

Here you will get 2 `16 x 16` arrays `g1` and `g2` that will store your `32` gray values.